# Secure communication on tclhttpd server fails

Tags: https, webserver, tcl, httpd.conf

I have a tclhttpd server and I am trying to communicate it using secure server (SSL). When I start my server, I get a notification that:

```
httpd started on port xxxx
secure httpd started on SSL port yyyy
```

When I try to access the normal HTTP (`http://localhost:xxxx`), I can access the web folder. However, when I am trying to access the web server through a browser using secure port and https (`https://localhost:yyyy`) it shows:

```
The connection to localhost was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

I've also used the `Httpd_SecureServer` call to initialize the server but i still cannot connect using ssl. 
What am I doing wrong here? any ideas?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think you need a certificate even when connecting to localhost.

Comment: Yeah, a certificate is required. For localhost, it can be self-signed without any deep problems, but your browser might still not like it. Of course, plain HTTP is secure on localhost too...